# Change visual design on the SQL Report Viewer

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

How do I change the visual design on SQL report viewer? And when I say report viewer I mean the hosting webpage, not the report itself.

Comment: You don't, you can create your own webpage and render the reports in there using an iframe

Comment: Oh okay. Well great that I got that clarified. You are welcome to make a reply post out of your comment and Ill mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, you can create your own webpage and render the reports in there using an iframe:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195191/Integration-of-SSRS-and-net-using-Iframe-and-URL-C

https://social.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/2d284a4e-af05-41c1-baf8-353f53bcfc2a/how-to-fit-ssrs-report-in-an-iframe